# Ubuntu lagging a lot in my laptop

Tags: 15.10, performance, gpu

I just installed Ubuntu on my PC, but it lags a lot. My pc runs all other OS at high speed, only Ubuntu is really slow.

**System specifications:**

- Lenovo y_40
- 8 GB RAM
- 500 GB HDD
- Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4
- AMD Radeon r9-m275
- using Ubuntu 15.10 (64bit)

Output of `lspci -k | grep -A 1 VGA` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the output of the terminal command `lspci -k | grep -A 2 VGA` which will show us more information about your graphics card and the used driver module.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers and choose a proprietary driver for your graphics card.

I assume that's what you mean with this limited information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the proprietary drivers from **additional drivers**, if you still experience lagging try Ubuntu **LTS** with proprietary drivers.